# Android. How to close all activities after a crash

Tags: android, crash

Is there a way to close all activities if a crassh occurs?

Thank you

Comment: guys, if you downvote, you can also comment it

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your own activities, as long as you're not doing something to cause them to run in separate processes (which should not normally be done), then they will close automatically because Android will kill your process.

Comment: I didn't downvote. If you're not placing your other activities in separate processes, then you don't need to do anything else. If you're trying to avoid the FC dialog and instead want to just shut down, this is possible too (by installing an uncaught exception handler, generally done in an overloaded Application class for your package).

Comment: Sorry for my comment. it's not my day. We solved the problem with uncaught exception handler. but we placed its initialization in the first activity, because we need context. and it seems, that application context is not good enough for us. Strange.